# Qt mouse event left button not translating qt object

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following mouse event on QGLWidget class ...

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPointF mousePosition = event->pos(); 
     float dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();
     float dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();

     if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
         setXRotation(xRot + 8.0 * dy);
         setYRotation(yRot + 8.0 * dx);
     } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
         xTrans += dx;
         yTrans -= dy;  
     }    
     lastPos = event->pos();
}
```

Rotation in paint GL is working but not translation.. What am I doing wrong... ?

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {

     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glPushMatrix();
     glLoadIdentity();
     glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
     glRotatef(xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glRotatef(yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
     glRotatef(zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


glTranslatef(xTrans, yTrans, 0.0f);
             glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    //draw function here
glPopMatrix();

            }
```

Comment: How and where are you drawing your models? Also, the way you wrote your `mouseMoveEvent` code, the right button should translate you model, not the left one.

Comment: I am drawing it in paintGL.. i have a drawfunction as shown..

Comment: Have you tried changing the first glTranslatef arguments to (xTrans, yTrans, -5.0), and removing the second glTranslatef?

Comment: What do you mean by translation is not working? Does it translate in the wrong direction, or not at all?

Comment: NOT TRANSLATING AT ALL!!!!!!!!.. @jhoffman0 - i tried that and it did  not work

Comment: Do xTrans and yTrans have the expected values after you right click?

Comment: they are initailly set to zero, I also print them out using qdebug.. they seemed large so I tried a few scaling things..

Comment: So if you call glTranslatef with large numbers, but it's not translating at all, then maybe the problem is in the draw function.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pop the matrix <strike>for it to get it applied</strike>.

http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/pop_and_push_matrices.html

<strike>That allows for the pushed matrix to actually finish calculating and get used.</strike>

```
glPopMatrix(); //end the current object transformations
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, every glPushMatrix should have a matching glPopMatrix, but you don't pop the matrix "for it to get applied", or to "finish calculating and get used". You pop the matrix to get rid of it.